# Python 3: Write CSV file to StringIO buffer in UTF-8 format.

Tags: python-3.x, csv, buffer

The following code writes a CSV file in UTF-8 format. The csv file is stored in the filesystem.

```
with open('sample.csv', 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as csvfile:
    spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=' ',
                            quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    csvfile.write('\ufeff')
    spamwriter.writerow("嗨")
```

Now I don't want to write to the fileystem anymore, I only want to store the CVS into a StringIO buffer. How should I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import csv
import os

filename = "temp.csv"
with open(filename, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as fp:
    fp.write('\ufeff')
    csv_writer = csv.writer(fp, quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    csv_writer.writerow(['嗨', '="00000011"', 'Lovely Spam', 'Wonderful Spam'])

buffer = open(filename, 'r').read()
print (buffer)
os.unlink(filename)


f= open("final.csv", "w")
f.write(buffer)
f.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just write the lines?

```
import io

s = io.StringIO()

with open('sample.csv') as file:
    for line in file:
        s.write(line)

s.seek(0)
for line in s:
    print(line)
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
    buf = StringIO()
    buf.write('\ufeff')
    writer = csv.writer(
        buf,
        "UNIX",
        delimiter=delimiter,
        quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL,
    )
    writer.writerow(h for h in header)
    for line in lines:
        writer.writerow(l for l in line)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).